# Using matplotlib checkbuttons in PyQT5

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

Is it possible to use matplotlib checkbuttons in a plot embedded in PyQT5?  The code is below, the plot works and it is embedded in a PyQT window but the checkbuttons do not add or remove the series as they should.  Code works fine when taken out of PyQT.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s0 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
        s1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
        s2 = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

        self.figure, ax = plt.subplots()
        l0, = ax.plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2, color='k', label='2 Hz')
        l1, = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2, color='r', label='4 Hz')
        l2, = ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2, color='g', label='6 Hz')
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

        self.lines = [l0, l1, l2]

        # Make checkbuttons with all plotted lines with correct visibility
        rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
        self.labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in self.lines]
        visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in self.lines]
        check = CheckButtons(rax, self.labels, visibility)
        check.on_clicked(self.b)
##        print('showing')
##        plt.show()


        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
##        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        # layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.canvas.draw()
##        print('done')
##        plt.show()

    def b(self,label):
        index = self.labels.index(label)
        self.lines[index].set_visible(not self.lines[index].get_visible())
        plt.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use matplotlib with Qt then you should not use pyplot but the Figure that is set on the canvas. Also "check" must be a member of the class.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QVBoxLayout

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons


class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))

        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s0 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        s1 = np.sin(4 * np.pi * t)
        s2 = np.sin(6 * np.pi * t)

        ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
        (l0,) = ax.plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2, color="k", label="2 Hz")
        (l1,) = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2, color="r", label="4 Hz")
        (l2,) = ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2, color="g", label="6 Hz")

        self.canvas.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

        self.lines = [l0, l1, l2]

        rax = self.canvas.figure.add_axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])

        self.labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in self.lines]
        visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in self.lines]

        self.check = CheckButtons(rax, self.labels, visibility)
        self.check.on_clicked(self.on_clicked)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def on_clicked(self, label):
        index = self.labels.index(label)
        self.lines[index].set_visible(not self.lines[index].get_visible())
        self.canvas.draw()


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```